# How to determine document size and/or enforce size limit?

Tags: arangodb

I have a scenario where I have Foxx service managing a collection with documents that follow a fixed schema for specific fields, but also allows extensions through a user-controlled "sub-document" (a field that can contain anything). While this works, I would like to limit the size of the "sub-document" to mitigate undesirable behaviors, such as users inserting large encoded binary data. Does anyone have recommendations on how to do this? I can't find any Javascript API calls to check document size (storage size).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at restricting the 'size' of some individual keys, or the overall document, or restricting the total count of root level keys?

Comment: The size of the whole document. By "size" I mean the data storage (or memory) footprint of the document - not the complexity of the structure.

Comment: Ok, If you're using Foxx then you have the option of JSON.Stringify'ing the document as it's being POST/PUT'ed and then you could just test the length of the generated string. That would be the easiest way to cap the size of a document before saving it.